# Why on Apple TV 4K, using Siri with "Move forward by 2 minutes" moved the movie back to near the beginning?

Tags: appletv, siri, 4k

When I was watching the movie at 00:50:00 (about 50 minutes into the movie), and I said to Siri on the Apple TV 4K, "Move forward by 2 minutes", it moved the movie to 00:02:00 (near the beginning of the movie), but if I was at 00:50:00 and I said, "Move backward by 2 minutes", it moved to 00:48:00?

I found that I could solve the problem by saying "**Skip** forward by 2 minutes", but why didn't the word "Move" work?

Answer (score 2):

Report the spoken phrase, expected outcome, actual outcome, and what Siri transcribed on screen, using [Apple’s feedback form](https://www.apple.com/feedback).

Siri has a lot of quirks like that where the outcome doesn’t match what you could reasonably expect. This comes down to Siri’s natural language processing simply needing refining.

I use Siri heavily on Apple Watch, and I used to encounter similar issues, but they got fixed within days or weeks after I reported them.

One example would be: “At 9 a.m., remind me to do X.” Occasionally, Siri understands, “**Add** 9 a.m., remind me to do X.” Yet for the longest time she would go ahead and create a reminder with no due date, even though she clearly understood the time part of my request. A few days after I reported this issue, Siri started correctly tacking on a due date even when she understands “add” instead of “at.”

Comment: oh I see, "move forward 2 minutes" is just not a *common* phrase for people to use, I see

Comment: Yeah, it’s not. But given the context (“forward”), one should still reasonably expect Siri to understand “skip.”

Comment: well siri's siri, and everyone knows that siri isn't the greatest.

Comment: @Phong when I said it wasn't common... I was saying it in a sarcastic way.

Comment: @startTerminal I just love comments that respond to something that doesn't even work well, "ABCD is ABCD", and "everyone knows XYZ isn't the greatest". Those are universally "powerful" phrases.